# What flag, if any, would have been more appropriate for this low-quality question?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

[This now-deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75918285/) consisted entirely of this text:

> Stackoverflow is Thinking add the IA to the webpage for users assist ?
>
> Nothing, I know they are going to fight to close this question.

I went to close-vote it (it was closed just before) and voted to delete it. But also flagged it with a custom flag saying:

> This reads as trolling close-voters to me.

This was on the theory that a moderator could have a quiet word, or if the account was known to the moderators they could take a more significant appropriate action.

It was declined with:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

The only standard flag that seems related is **Rude or abusive**, and I've had R/A flags declined for things that were much ruder than this question, so I've since reserved it for really outrageously rude things. Passive-aggressive trolling didn't seem to rise to the level.

What standard flag would have been appropriate, or was there no call for a flag at all? Just so I know for next time.

Comment: Note that flagging also includes flagging for improvement, which is equal to close voting above 3k rep.

Comment: There's no real reason for a mod to contact the user directly in this case; they aren't violating any rules, they simply posted an off topic question. VLQ would likely be appropriate on other stacks for a question like this, but VLQ isn't all that useful here given the volume.

Comment: @KevinB - Well, trolling is against our rules. But in retrospect, yeah, I think no flag at all.

Comment: It is not certain that is trolling, rather than a sincere post intended for meta.

Comment: The second sentence looks like trolling close voters to me, but given the very low quality of the question, the apparent bad attitude of the questioner, and the fact that it's a new account I just think disposing of the question with as few SO cycles as possible is best.

Comment: It could be nominated for a *[How is babby formed?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed)* award. "IA" looks like obfuscation of "ChatGPT" (AI).

Comment: Would the "not about programming..." flag not be appropriate here? As someone who can't cast close votes, I see myself either downvoting and moving on or using that flag, not sure if it would have been declined though.

Comment: @MissSkooter - That's a close vote reason. I went to do that and it was closed as I was doing so, so I voted to delete. This isn't about closing/deleting the question, but about flagging it.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I honestly didn't know these two things were different. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @MissSkooter: Users without the [privilege to cast close/reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can instead flag those posts with a relevant close reason, which can cause them to be sent to the relevant review queue. But yeah, beyond that, close votes are different from flags. :)

Comment: Not related to the question, but I believe the message system should change according to the user's RP. Saying *"Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags"* to a person that has 1,000,000 rp is a bit patronizing.

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae - :-) Heh, not a worry. Just because I have rep doesn't mean I've read the flags documentation! (I have, but...)

Comment: It reads like a Meta question (asking about SO itself rather than programming), not that I can tell what's actually be asked due to the incredibly poor language. The quality is so low that migrating it doesn't make sense, of course. Actually, the language is so bad that I wouldn't make *any* assumptions about the user intentionally trying to provoke people or not.

Answer (score 23):

In retrospect, I think the best course was not to flag at all, just do the other things I did (VTC — but it was closed as I reached for that — and then vote to delete). The question was en route to being closed, was being actively downvoted, and speculating that moderators might find it appropriate to do something more, especially given their workload, didn't really make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 13):

In truth, all you probably needed to do here was vote to close (VTC) the question (there are several options such as unclear or not about programming) and downvote. If the question was closed, and had enough downvotes then voting to delete would have also been fine.

If you did feel compelled to flag then use a "Very low quality" which would have likely forced it into the Close Votes review queue, if it wasn't in there already. There was, however, no requirement for moderator involvement (which is what a custom moderator flag is requesting). The curators in the community handled the post without issue, by VTCing and voting the delete. Moderators are for handling the exceptions, when users can't handle the problem.